# Installing a library using npm

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I've a question regarding how to use a js library that is installed via npm. I have a simple webapp that compiles using gulp, so I installed the library using --save to populate my package.json but now what? should I add it as a gulp task too? I am not clear about all this process. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost always, libraries installed using `npm i --save` are ready to be `require()`d right out of the box.

The gulp tasks you might see on a library's source in GitHub is for developers of that library to build and test the library locally.

npm has utilities for running all of the build tools automatically before the library is published (with `npm publish`) and while the consumer's (yours) `npm install` is running.

Comment: Solved using Bower. Much easier. Thanks!